# Callback функции создания таблицы mysql в nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

Есть функция, которая при запуске создает базу даных,

```
 function showDb() {
        pool.query("show databases like 'bt' ",function (err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (rows.length == 0) {
                console.log(' database "bt" NOT exist ');
                creatDb();
            } else {
            console.log(' database "bt" exist /n');
            process.exit();
        }
        });
    }

    function creatDb() {
        pool.query('CREATE DATABASE bt ',function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            usingDb();
        });

    }

    function usingDb() {
        pool.query('USE bt ',function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            creatTableUsers();
        });
    }

    function creatTableUsers() {
        pool.query(
            "CREATE TABLE users (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))",
            function (err) {
                if (err) throw err
                insertIntoUsers();
            });

    }

    function insertIntoUsers() {
        pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('BP'),('Shell'),('Statoil'),('Total'),('Helm'),('Vinmar'),('Interchem')",
            function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
    }



    showDb();
```

Почему не выполняеться функция insertIntoUsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому будет интересно пофиксил тем что из функции `showDb` строку `process.exit();` скопировал в функцию `insertIntoUsers`